# ModelState.IsValid Return False Even There is No Error Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I read many of the questions about `if(ModelState.IsValid)` returns false with error, I also tried this code:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

to find what error but it shows no error in it.
But `if(ModelState.Isvalid)` returns always false. I don't known what mistake I've done in Model, Controller or View.

Model:

```
public class AdminSignup
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Contact Person is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
   
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Email Id is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="User Name is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Password is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Apartment Name is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string ApartmentName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Location/City is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string LocationCity { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Apartment Address is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string ApartmentAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Apartment PhoneNumber is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string ApartmentPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="NoOfUnits is Required",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string NoOfUnits { get; set; }     
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult signup(AdminSignup asign)
{
    if ( ModelState.IsValid)
    {                           
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        //con.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into AdminSignup (ApartmentName,ContactPerson,LocationCity,ApartmentAddress,ApartmentPhoneNumber,EmailId,NoOfUnits)  values('" + asign.ApartmentName + "','" + asign.ContactPerson + "','" + asign.LocationCity + "','" + asign.ApartmentAddress + "','" + asign.ApartmentPhoneNumber + "','" + asign.EmailId + "','" + asign.NoOfUnits + "')", con);
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //AdminSignup adminsignup = new AdminSignup
        //{
        //    EmailId = asign.EmailId
        //};

        //TempData["EmailId"] = adminsignup;

        //con.Close();
        return RedirectToAction("SignupStep2");
    }
    return View();    
}
```

And View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("signup", "Apartment", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @Id = "first-form" }))
{
  //@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="apartment_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apartment Name &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @* <input class="form-control" id="apartment_name" placeholder="Apartment Name" type="text" name="apartment_name">*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApartmentName, new {@class="form-control",@Id="ApartmentName",placeholder="Apartment Name" })   
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ApartmentName)                           
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="contact_person" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact Person &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @*<input class="form-control" id="contact_person" placeholder="Password" type="text" name="contact_person">*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactPerson, new {@class="form-control",@Id="ContactPerson",placeholder="Contact Person" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ContactPerson)
      </div>
    </div>            
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="loc_city" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Location / City &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @* <input class="form-control" id="loc_city" placeholder="Location / City" type="text" name="loc_city">*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocationCity, new {@class="form-control",@Id="LocationCity",placeholder="Location/City" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.LocationCity)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="apt_address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apartment Address &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @*<textarea name="apt_address" id="" cols="10" rows="5" class="form-control">Apartment Address</textarea>*@
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ApartmentAddress, new {@class="form-control",@Id="ApartmentAddress" ,placeholder="Apartment Address" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ApartmentAddress)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="apt_number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apartment PhoneNumber &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @*<input class="form-control" id="apt_number" placeholder="Apartment Number" type="text" name="apt_number">*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApartmentPhoneNumber, new {@class="form-control",@Id="ApartmentPhoneNumber",placeholder="Apartment PhoneNumber" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ApartmentPhoneNumber)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="apt_emailid" class="col-sm-3 control-lable">Email Id &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailId, new {@class="form-control",@Id="Email Id",placeholder="EmailId" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.EmailId)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="apt_units" class="col-sm-3 control-label">No of Units &nbsp; <sup>*</sup></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @*<input class="form-control" id="apt_units" placeholder="No of Units" type="text" name="apt_units">*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NoOfUnits, new {@class="form-control",@Id="NoOfUnits",placeholder="No.Of.Units" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.NoOfUnits)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <input type="submit" value="Next" name="first_form" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_first"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any form control in your view for the required `Password` property (and since its required, `ModelState` will be invalid)

Comment: Or `UserName` !

Comment: Sorry i added it in another page so This is the error??

Comment: I'm add both username and password into another page

Comment: That has nothing to do with this view. You not posting a value for those 2 properties so `ModelState` is invalid because you have a `[Required]` attribute on them

Comment: ok now it works.. fine Thanks..!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just wonder why you do not post an answer instead giving the answer by comment. :)

Comment: @ibubi Because Valkyriee has already added one :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, actually it is for this time, but, as I am following `asp.net-mvc` tag most of your true acceptable answers living in comments :) I guess you fell into a bad habit. Forgive my curiosity btw :)

Comment: @ibubi, Writing a good answer takes time, and I do not always have the time :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke credit is all yours :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your view and model again, you have put required on all your properties within the `class`, however you are returning `7 of 9` properties. then `Model.IsValid` will look at your `Model` and see oh look there `2 required properties` that you are not `returning`, so it will be false. either remove `[required]` on those properties or add them within your view. good luck.

**Update**
Those 2 Properties are:

`UserName` And `Password`, they need to be within your `Html.BeginForm`, so they will be send to server as the part of your class.

Comment: I'm put those UserName and Password in another view so that will be the error,I remove it,Now it return true Thanks for your help :)